# W10: Fingerprint reader degraded accuracy

Tags: lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, authentication, fingerprint, windows-hello

I have a Windows 10 Lenovo Laptop that has a "Synaptics UWP WBDI" Fingerprint reader, all drivers and firmware versions are up to date.

I'd register my fingerprints with Windows Hello and they would work fine, laptop would unlock after barely touching the reader, then after 2 or 3 days the accuracy of the reader gets degraded to the point that it no longer recognizes any of my (registered) fingerprints.

I've tried to re-register my fingerprints multiple times, uninstalling the drivers and reinstalling them, bios resets, laptop factory resets and this keeps going on. I have an Ipad, Dell Laptop and two Samsung Phones that have no problems recognizing them at the same time.

Before you ask, there is no dust or grease buildup on the reader whatsoever. Any ideas what may be going on ?

Comment: I would try turning off the power management so we can at least rule that out. In device manager, go to properties of the fingerprint reader and look in the power management tab. Uncheck 'allow this computer to turn off the device to save power' and save.
See how you go.

Comment: What's going on? Cheap/lame hardware?

Comment: This is a bussiness Thinkpad laptop, with top notch specs (and price). SHOULD NOT  have a FPR reader that qualifies as cheap/lame